# Masking with transparent PNG in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i want to mask objects with dynamic transparent PNG files in Flash Action Script 3.0

if you have any solution regrading that please forward..

Thank you,
Hardik

Comment: I know one not easy way , but in animations it will kill cpu . You can draw mask target to bitmap and then check from png which pixels are transparent to erase it from target .

Comment: By dynamic, do you mean that the tranparent PNG is going to change like an animation, or is it dynamic in that it could be one of multiple PNGs that are used?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that by dynamic PNG you just mean one that has been loaded by code at run time. There is nothing special to that, the same answer applies as to any library object imported as a Bitmap and then set to use lossless compression.

In order to do this the png to be used as a mask must be embedded in a [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) (typically a Sprite, a MovieClip or even a Loader). The DisplayObject class has a property [cacheAsBitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap) and you need to set that property to true for both the DisplayObject holding the mask and the one holding the content to be masked. Then assign the mask by code to let the mask reveal the content.

Example:

```
//myClip is the MovieClip or Sprite or even Loader holding the content
myClip.cacheAsBitmap=true;
//myMask is a MovieClip or Sprite or even Loader containing the transparent PNG
myMask.cacheAsBitmap=true;

//set up the mask to reveal the content where the PNG is not transparent
myClip.mask=maskClip;
```

Answer (score -1):

PhotonStorm has an [implementation](http://www.photonstorm.com/flixel-power-tools/flxdisplay) of this that you could dig through and figure out how they do it.

Comment: To whoever downvoted 3 years later, please add a comment as to what's wrong with my answer so I can improve it. Or better yet; you could edit it to be more correct, or give a better answer.

Comment: Even three years ago this should not have been an answer, it should have been a comment. Therefore another downvote.